# Use Intellisense when using p5js in instance mode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, processing, p5.js, jsdoc

I'm trying to write a little website in expressjs and p5js, but I ran in a uncomfortable problem with p5js and intellisense in VSCode. My problem is this:

I'm using p5js in instance mode as I want to have more than one canvas on the page. To do that you define something like this

```
const mySketch = (sketch) => {
  let x = 100;
  let y = 100;

  sketch.setup = () => {
    sketch.createCanvas(500, 400);
  };

  sketch.draw = () => {
    sketch.background(0);
    sketch.fill(255);
    sketch.rect(x, y, 50, 50);
  };
};

new p5(mySketch); // invoke p5
```

To use Intellisense with p5js in VSCode I installed @types/p5 and added this to the jsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6"
    },
    "include": [
        "*.js",
        "**/*.js",
        "node_modules/@types/p5/**/*"
    ]
}
```

This allowed me to get the definitions of the methods/functions, the parameters, ecc.., WHEN called directly.
So if called `circle(10, 10, 5)` and I put the mouse over the function VSCode told me the documentation about that specific command originating from the global.d.ts file in the @types/p5/ folder.

When using p5js in instance mode, you do not call directly the methods themselves, but you call them from the (sketch) parameter you passed at the beginning (so `sketch.circle(10, 10, 5)` for example).

Now: how can I get the documentation that is already present in the @types/p5 folder to work when I call them with `sketch.method()`?

I tried with JSDoc like this

```
/**
 *
 * @param{p5} sketch
 */
const mySketch = (sketch) => {
  s.setup = () => { }
[...]
```

But it didn't work.

Right now if I mouse-over with `circle()` I get:

```
Draws a circle to the canvas. A circle is a round shape. Every point on the edge of a circle is the same distance from its center. By default, the first two parameters set the location of the center of the circle. The third parameter sets the shape's width and height (diameter). The origin may be changed with the ellipseMode() function.

@param x — x-coordinate of the center of the circle.

@param y — y-coordinate of the center of the circle.

@param d — diameter of the circle.

@chainable
```

If I do the same thing with `sketch.circle()` I get `any`.

This is probably caused by my ignorance of VSCode but I can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score -1):

What you've done with your JSDoc `@param {p5} sketch` is good. You can also write `const mySketch = (/**@type {p5}*/sketch) => {`. Or if you're using TypeScript, `const mySketch = (sketch: p5) => {`.

What you're missing is something like a module import if that works for your usage of p5. Ex. `import p5 from "p5";` at the top of your file. If you don't want to do an actual module import, then try adding `/** @typedef {import("p5")} p5 */` somewhere in your file.

Your addition of `"node_modules/@types/p5/**/*"` to the `includes` property of your tsconfig is useless.